# Can books be transferred from Nooks to Kindles and back?

Tags: kindle, drm, conversion, nook

I'm currently using a Nook, but considering switching to Kindle hardware. Is there a simple way to keep books synced across devices, or at least to move purchased ebooks from one to the other?

Answer (score 6):

You may want to try using the [Calibre Ebook Manager](http://calibre-ebook.com/) with the [deDRM](http://apprenticealf.wordpress.com/2012/09/10/drm-removal-tools-for-ebooks/) plugin to get the ebook files, sans-DRM, and then move them onto the Kindle. It works, but it won't sync them or automatically move newly purchased books; each book must be done individually. 
The Digital Reader has some helpful tutorials on how to do this:

[To strip DRM from Kindle ebooks](http://www.the-digital-reader.com/2012/09/15/how-add-kindle-drm-removal-plugin-calibre/#.UrImD_RDsjI)

[To strip DRM from Nook ebooks](http://www.the-digital-reader.com/2012/09/27/how-to-add-a-nook-drm-removal-plugin-to-calibre/#.UrIl-_RDsjI)

Note that DRM removal is illegal in some countries. Please read and follow your local copyright laws.

Comment: It may be illegal to remove the DRM from an EBook depending on where you live.  You should only remove DRM if you are legally allowed to do so.

Answer (score 6):

The most effective way to manage your Nook books on your Kindle (without removing the DRM) is to obtain the [Nook for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=bn.ereader&hl=en) app and sideload it on to the Kindle (you'll need a Fire or later model to do this).

If you don't have another Android device handy, you will need to find a means to download the Nook APK file to your computer.